# Adding or Editing Civirule where Linked Trigger = "webform is submitted" returns error

Tags: webform-civicrm, civirules, drupal-9

Civicrm version: 5.45.1
Drupal 9.3.3

Adding (or editing an existing) civirule where the selected trigger is "webform is submitted" generates the fatal error:

> CiviRule trigger class "CRM_WebformCivirules_Trigger" does not exist

excerpt from the Drupal log:

> $Fatal Error Details = array:3 [ "message" => "CiviRule trigger class
> "CRM_WebformCivirules_Trigger" does not exist" "code" => null
> "exception" => Exception {#3523 #message: "CiviRule trigger class
> "CRM_WebformCivirules_Trigger" does not exist" #code: 0 #file:
> "/***/***/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/BAO/Trigger.php"
> #line: 166 trace: { /***/***/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/BAO/Trigger.php:166
> { CRM_Civirules_BAO_Trigger::getTriggerObjectByClassName($className,
> $abort = true) › › throw new Exception('CiviRule trigger class "' .
> $className . '" does not exist'); › } }

Other rules are working fine, only the 'webform is submitted' trigger fails.
I've not been able to find any information on this error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: is it possible the 'webform submitted' trigger was built for d7 webforms and you are trying it with d9?

Comment: I've thought this might be the issue, but I don't know how to test or work out if it is.

Comment: create the simplest possible webform in both D7 and D9 and compare outcomes?

Comment: then open an Issue via https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues and at least have helped by reporting the error even if you can't fix it

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded my D7 site to D9 (and don't have any other D7 sites), but had been using Civirules with the 'webform submitted' trigger without error for a few years. (However, I only switch on the rules for Feb-Mar). I don't think a simpler webform will help with testing as the error occurs in the civirules UI when moving to the next screen or when saving the rule. I guess setting up a separate D9 site could provide a test

Comment: does that mean you can replicate just in civirules eg on https://d9-master.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/civirule/form/rule?reset=1&action=add - guessing not as i dn't see a trigger for webform probably as webform not enabled.

Comment: if you make a new rule on yours do you see the trigger?

Comment: i tried on a d9 site with webform and get 'no results' if i search in trigger for 'webform'

Comment: can you work around by using another type of trigger, eg if the webform adds a tag, or adds them to a group.

Comment: Yep, this is what I did. Thanks.

Comment: i will add that as an Answer so SE doesn't grumble about Questions not getting answered

Comment: would be good if you +1 and Accept (tick)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps work around by using another type of trigger, eg if the webform adds a tag, or adds them to a group